# fetchAll() is printing the data twice

Tags: php

I'm having a problem when I fetch data using 2 `foreach()`

The problem when I load the page I get the same row twice.

For example `$row['1']`:

```
$row['1'] = "Name";
```

I get this :

```
NAME
NAME
```

My code :

```
$query = "SELECT gid,group_time,name_student,certificate_id,course_id,course_title,course_days FROM  groups JOIN students JOIN courses  WHERE group_id = ? ";
$q = $connection->prepare($query);
if(!$q){

  die("rip".mysqli_error($connection));
}
$q->bindparam(1,$gid);
$q->execute();
$all = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This is my table :

```
<table dir="rtl" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>

<tr>


    <th class="text-center">name of student</th>

    <?php
    foreach($all as $r2){

      echo '<div dir="ltr"class="h4 text-center " style="text-decoration:underline;text-decoration-skip: ink;">report</div>';
      echo '<div dir="ltr"class="h3 text-center" style="text-decoration:underline;text-decoration-skip: ink;">'.$r2['course_title'].'('.$r2['group_time'].')</div>';
echo "<br>";
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $r2['course_days']; $i++) {

        echo "<td class='text-center'>$i</td>";
    }

}

    ?>

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>



<?php
foreach($all as $r){
echo "<tr>";
print "<td class='text-center'>".$r['name_student']."</td>";

for ($i = 1; $i <= $r['course_days']; $i++) {

    print "<td></td>";
}
echo "</tr>";

}

?>


</tbody>

</table>
```

screenshot of the problem :
[image]
So I saw couple questions about the same topic But all the solutions didn't work for :\

I tried to use :

```
$q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Instead of `fetchAll();`

But it is not working.

Its the same problem if i used while loop

Comment: Have you done a `print_r($row);`?

Comment: your query is returning correct data  from database??

Comment: @AjAX. for the first foreach It gave me this array :
Array ( [gid] => 31 [group_time] => 10-6 [name_student] => asasaszx [certificate_id] => 4 [course_id] => 4 [course_title] => Compter fixing [course_days] => 30 ) it gave me the array twice

Comment: @VickyGill I'm pretty sure its not from the query the query looks good

Comment: Have you tried commenting one foreach loop ??

Comment: @VickyGill The problem is in the first foreach() the second one working fine

Comment: Do you have  `phpMyAdmin` to check quickly what is in the `database`? Perhaps it is the `insert`.

Comment: I did check the insert everything inserted fine :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your DB is MySQL.

Your PHP code looks fine but this query can hardly be correct and is  probably the source of your issue :

```
SELECT id,group_time,name_student,certificate_id,course_id,course_title,course_days 
FROM  groups 
JOIN students 
JOIN courses  
WHERE group_id = ?
```

Your JOINs don't have a `ON` clause. This means they are interpreted as `CROSS JOIN`, this results in a **Cartesian product** between your 3 tables. And so you have too much rows returned

You should do something like

```
SELECT id,group_time,name_student,certificate_id,course_id,course_title,course_days     
FROM  groups G
JOIN students S ON G.id=S.group_id
JOIN courses  C ON G.id=C.group_id
WHERE group_id = ?
```

Its impossible to give you the right answer for your query since you have not shown the structure of your 3 tables

Comment: I changed the query it works fine when 1 row is shown .. but if I added the 2nd row like  2 students the whole thing breaks Check the [ScreenShot](http://prntscr.com/jfwffd)

Comment: When I used Break: between the for loops its fetching normal!